# Error building jar for kotlin in IntelliJ for desktop

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, compiler-errors, compose-desktop

I'm trying to build an executable jar file for the a demo desktop project with IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.4 (Community Edition). The kotlin project is the "hello word" that intelliJ creates by default. When I follow all the steps to build the jar file , I receive this error:

Kotlin: The provided plugin androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.ComposePluginRegistrar is not compatible with this version of compiler.
I'm using the following versions for Kotlin Compiler and compose compiler:

`plugins { kotlin("jvm").version("1.9.22") id("org.jetbrains.compose").version("1.5.12") }`

I've tried to force the compose compiler 1.5.8 that is the compatible with 1.5.12 compose , but it doesn't work:

`compose { kotlinCompilerPlugin.set("1.5.8") }`

I've installed the Compose Multiplatform IDE support Plugin 1.5.12
Target JVM is 1.8.
Gradle JVM is JDK-21 version 21.0.2

I'd like to know how to proceed to succesfully compile my jar file.

Comment: Did you create one using https://kmp.jetbrains.com/ ? Any chance to share the project's full source code via Google Drive or github?

Comment: I attach a link to my demo project where the error building the jar appears and the complete error message . As you propose I've also created a project for desktop using kmp.jetbrains.com but in this case I can't execute it , when I run the main file I receive an error like:  "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError "  . additionally when I try to build the jar , the message I receive is   "Executing post-compile tasks…" and never ends..
 LINK TO THE FILES https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15cuURJC2vtQiaPu9NbSkmMYvO9mdstO3?usp=sharing

Comment: Same issue. I've just put up question here on SO but I'm not hopeful of any answers. I can debug and run my project from IntelliJ no problem but can't build a .jar to release.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using artifact building ,so I'm now playing with Compose Multiplatform Gradle plugin to build an installation package (.msi) for windows.   the command is: ./gradlew packageDistributionForCurrentOS
# outputs are written to build/compose/binaries  .   The site with info : https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/blob/master/tutorials/Native_distributions_and_local_execution/README.md

Comment: I tried your project file demo.zip, and the IDE reports that:Found invalid Gradle JVM configuration

JDK 21.0.1 isn't compatible with Gradle 8.3. Please fix JAVA_HOME environment variable.

So I switch to JDK 17 and able to build a jar file.

Comment: , I've applied your fix with success.Many thanks Jacky

Answer (score 2):

I've finally succeded by using Compose Multiplatform Gradle plugin to build an installation package (.msi) for windows instead build an artifact.
In intellij the gradle command I've used to build the msi file is: ./gradlew packageDistributionForCurrentOS.